# Cut off a part of canvas

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

I have a canvas with graph, i get it from server. Sometimes the graph is not in the center. Now i want to cut off the rest part of canvas. I have the graph max and min x,y points. Ho to cut off the rest part of canvas? I can't find a solution.

Comment: Could you please tell me under what condition is the canvas not in the center? And please post detailed codes.

Answer (score 1):

First create a tempBitmap of size full width and Height like this

```
 Bitmap tempImage =  Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);      

 Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempImage, (int) minX, (int) minY, width, height);
```

here finalBitmap is that which you want.
You can draw it in canvas and also save as bitmap.